# Get link from anchor tag using Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to get value of a `href` attribute from an `anchor` tag (`a` tag) using Java, without a third party API. I know the class of the label. The website looks like this:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="uix_wrapper">
      <div id="button">
          <label class="downloadButton">
            <a href="link that I want to get">Button</a>
          </label>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well, what have you tried? What was the problem you have encountered?

Comment: You're better off using an API like Jodd.

Comment: If parsing XHTML, use XPath.  If parsing HTML, load the page as an HTMLDocument.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression if you try to avoid using any third-party libraries. A very basic expression for your example is

```
<a href="(.*?)">
```

and should work. You can try out yourself using https://www.debuggex.com/

The result will be in the second group.

Comment: Uh, read [classical regex and html question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).